# Any Execution of SSIS in Debug w/ x64 Generates DTSRuntimeWrap Error

Tags: ssis

I've tested this with simple 1 step (non script tasks) on 2 different laptops.

> Windows 10 Professional or  Enterprise x64 Visual Studio 2019
> Enterprise or Community (Latest) SSDT and SSIS Extension: latest

Using debug mode, if i run a simple 1 step package with x64 emulation turned off, it runs fine. If I turn it on, it fails with DTSRuntimeWrap error.

My test package just has 1 task, an expression that assigns a number to variable

I understand that from within SQL Server it will run in x64 (that's the version we have).

> Failed to start project Library not registered. (Exception from
> HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap)
>
> Program Location:
>
> at
> Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.LaunchVsDebugger(Boolean
> isRemoteTest, IVsDebugger iVsDebugger,
> DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)    at
> Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.ValidateAndRunDebugger(Int32
> flags, IOutputWindow outputWindow,
> DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)    at
> Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32
> launchOptions, ProjectItem startupProjItem,
> DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)    at
> Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchActivePackage(Int32
> launchOptions)    at
> Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.LaunchDtsPackage(Int32
> launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)
> at
> Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsProjectDebugger.Launch(Int32
> launchOptions, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)

Comment: This issue is fixed as part of SSDT add-on bug fix. [Reference release notes](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects&ssr=false#overview)

Answer (score 2):

I ran the SQL Server Installer again and did a repair, which seems to have resolved it for me.

I think it has to do with these dlls. Your's may be in a different folder.

C:\Windows\system32>%windir%\syswow64\regsvr32 "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\dts\binn\dts.dll

C:\Windows\system32>%windir%\syswow64\regsvr32 "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\dts\binn\MsDtsSrvrUtil.dll

Comment: "I ran the SQL Server Installer again and did a repair, which seems to have resolved it for me." - I thought those folders were created by SQL Server Data Tools? Did you install them by creating a local SQL Server instance?

Comment: The SQL Server instance was already installed and I later added the SSIS capabilities. I actually had the same issue again the other day and used the same repair technique to fix it. I assume it re-registers some required DLL files.